# Subtypes and Spring inter-dependency resolution vs autowiring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm trying to understand why the Spring bean inter-dependency resolving works differently than the autowiring.

Given we have two classes A and B, where B extends A:

```
public class A {}

public class B {} extends A {}
```

Following Java configuration:

```
@Configuration
public class TestConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public A a() {
        return new A();
    }

    @Bean
    public B b() {
        return new B();
    }

    @Bean
    public A testBean(A bean) {
        return bean;
    }

}
```

produces this error:

```
Description:

Parameter 0 of method testBean in com.so.demo.TestConfiguration required a single bean, but 2 were found:
    - a: defined by method 'a' in class path resource [com/so/demo/TestConfiguration.class]
    - b: defined by method 'b' in class path resource [com/so/demo/TestConfiguration.class]


Action:

Consider marking one of the beans as @Primary, updating the consumer to accept multiple beans, or using @Qualifier to identify the bean that should be consumed
```

**WRONG ASSUMPTION** (See below quote):

But if I remove **testBean** from the configuration and try autowiring the bean of type A:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication implements ApplicationRunner {

    @Autowired
    A a; 

    @Override
    public void run(ApplicationArguments arg0) throws Exception {
        System.out.println(a.getClass().getName());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

autowired field will be of the correct type A. Also if I remove A bean from the configuration and leave only B bean, then B bean will be autowired to the field DemoApplication#a. Which is the behavior I'd expect in this case.

---

Now my question is, why autowiring correctly deduce the type (Using exact type and not subclass) even when there are two possible candidates (one being subclass)? But injecting dependency in configuration results in above error.

Thanks to @Sotirios Delimanolis for clarifying this part:

> So my assumption was wrong. Autowiring works just because it failback to by-name autowiring. If I change the field names in DemoApplication not to match bean names it will fail the same way as configuration class.

Is there a way to force resolving dependency by exact type?

---

> I've created this simple example just to help clarifying what my
>   question is. In reality I have two different libraries based on Spring
>   boot, one has dependency on supertype, the other on subtype, and I'm
>   getting described collision because first library's autoconfiguration
>   fails since it can't decide on what bean to inject having both
>   supertype and subtype in the bean pool.
>
> [FYI] by-name bean resolution is not what I'm looking for.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Change your `a` field's name to something else. It'll fail then. It's falling back to the bean name resolution.

Comment: Thanks, but this is exactly what I said, I don't want by-name resolution, maybe the last part of the question is a bit confusing.

Comment: So you know the answer to _Now my question is, why autowiring correctly deduce the type (Using exact type and not subclass) even when there are two possible candidates (one being subclass)?_ Edit that out.

Comment: Well that is my question, if someone could explain why is there difference in picking the bean between autowiring and dependency injection in a configuration bean.

Comment: I don't understand why you think there's a difference. They're both resolved the same way as far as your example goes. If the parameter/field name is `a`, it will fall back to "by name". If it's not, there's no fall back, so it fails because there are two candidate beans.

Comment: I've removed the last example because it was confusing people (It was just the example of what I don't want). There is a difference. Injecting by-type will work for the autowiring but not for the dependency injection inside configuration class. So I'd like to know - why that difference? And is there a way to tell Spring to inject the inter-dependency by the exact type in the configuration class?

Comment: _Injecting by-type will work for the autowiring_ No. It's just falling back to the name of the bean. There's is no difference. Change your `testBean` method's parameter name to be `a` and you'll see the same behavior.

Comment: If your question is just _Is there a way to force resolving dependency by exact type?_ then we can move to that, but your current assumption is incorrect.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying this. If you could answer the second question and put it in the form of answer I'll be glad to accept it.

Comment: `@Bean` exposes an `autowire` element which you can set to `Autowire.BY_TYPE` to force Spring to use "by type" for autowiring the corresponding bean's bean properties after the method has returned. It doesn't apply to the `@Bean` method itself though and not to `@Autowired` fields either, they have to be setters. This doesn't really work for you because your `@DemoApplication` is not made a bean through a `@Bean` method and that behavior won't apply to `@Bean` factory methods. I'm not able to find something that applies to those at the moment.

Comment: I can't find anything that forces it everywhere, seems the fallback is intrinsic. Are you just trying to detect errors for multiple candidate beans? Maybe some strict bean naming conventions might help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146370/discussion-between-matej-and-sotirios-delimanolis).